# I was trying to create a new Liferay Plugin Project and it showed the following error

Tags: eclipse-plugin, liferay, portlet

```
I changed the ivy.jar.url to the above mentioned url and now it came up with    a new error as follows:
[Console output redirected to
```

file:C:\Rahul13615\liferay.metadata.plugins\com.liferay.ide.sdk.core\sdk.log]
Buildfile: C:\Rahul13615\liferay\plugins\portlets\build.xml
[get] Getting: https://repository.liferay.com/nexus/content/repositories/liferay-public-snapshots/com/liferay/org.apache.ivy/2.4.0.LIFERAY-PATCHED-1-SNAPSHOT/org.apache.ivy-2.4.0.LIFERAY-PATCHED-1-SNAPSHOT.jar
[get] To: C:\Rahul13615\liferay\plugins.ivy\org.apache.ivy-2.4.0.LIFERAY-PATCHED-1-SNAPSHOT.jar
  [taskdef] Could not load definitions from resource org/apache/ivy/ant/antlib.xml. It could not be found.

BUILD FAILED
C:\Rahul13615\liferay\plugins\portlets\build.xml:5: The following error occurred while executing this line:

C:\Rahul13615\liferay\plugins\build-common-plugins.xml:5: The following error occurred while executing this line:

C:\Rahul13615\liferay\plugins\build-common.xml:47: The following error occurred while executing this line:

C:\Rahul13615\liferay\plugins\build-common-ivy.xml:102: The following error occurred while executing this line:

C:\Rahul13615\liferay\plugins\build-common-ivy.xml:38: The following error occurred while executing this line:

C:\Rahul13615\liferay\plugins\build-common-ivy.xml:48: Problem: failed to create task or type antlib:org.apache.ivy.ant:settings

Cause: The name is undefined.
Action: Check the spelling.
Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.
Action: Check that any / declarations have taken place.
No types or tasks have been defined in this namespace yet

This appears to be an antlib declaration. 
Action: Check that the implementing library exists in one of:
        -ANT_HOME\lib
        -the IDE Ant configuration dialogs

Total time: 11 seconds

Comment: Please share what are you trying to achieve along with errors faced and what did you change?The only thing I can see are the logs.

Answer (score 1):

Below please find my steps how I created a new Liferay Plugin Project.
I hope this will be useful to you:

1. I have downloaded Liferay Developer Studio 3.0.1. GA2 from:
   htt ps://web.liferay.com/downloads/liferay-projects/liferay-ide or
   ht tps://sourceforge.net/projects/lportal/files/Liferay%20IDE/
   Note: there are some known issue with the 3.0.0 version
2. I extracted the IDE to C:\dstudio3 on my computer
3. I downloaded the Liferay SDK from:
   http s://www.liferay.com/downloads?559250categoryIds=559255
   (bottom of the page, additional files section)
4. I copied the SDK to the IDE's folder and created a personalized build.peter.properties file, based on:
   htt ps://web.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/76813485
5. I started Eclipse and set up a new Liferay Server environment
6. In Eclipse, I created a new "Liferay Plugin Project", and in the wizard, I defined the location of the Plugins SDK.
7. I created a new Liferay Portlet project inside the Plugin project.

Best Regards,
Peter